# AE.Net.Mail Search By SentOn DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello all i am try to search my gmail using AE.NET.Mail.
But i am facing a problem when i tried to search email using SentOn method it's always retruning **`xm006 BAD Could not parse command`**.
I am sening this Datetime Fromat yyyy-MM-dd

Can you guys please help me what is the problem here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug filed about this exact problem on AE.Net.Mail's GitHub issues page here: https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/issues/197

AE.Net.Mail is unlikely to get a fix anytime soon as the project is unmaintained.

Your best option is probably to switch to my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library which does not have this problem and is actively maintained as well.

Answer (score 1):

A little late for this but I guess it could help someone. Since gmail doesn't allow anymore the same DateTime param. A workaround must be made:

```
imapClient.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
SearchCondition condition = new SearchCondition();
condition.Field = SearchCondition.Fields.Since;
condition.Value = new DateTime(2019, 2, 12).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
var messages = imapClient.SearchMessages(condition);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me - seems like it's the date format the library needs.